# How to read and save ini file to a list

Tags: c#, ini

I have searched here and not found an answer that addresses my issue, I have a program that reads a report (txt file) and automatically populates specific cells of a worksheet in a workbook. I have created an ini file that the user will update as and when needed. 
The issue I am having is I want to read the ini file and save the contents of certain sections to their own lists. Here is my code:

```
public class IniFile
{

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key,
           string Value, StringBuilder Result, int Size, string FileName);


    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, int Key,
           string Value, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] Result,
           int Size, string FileName);


    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(int Section, string Key,
           string Value, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] Result,
           int Size, string FileName);

    public string path;
    public IniFile(string INIPath)
    {
        path = INIPath;
    }

    public string[] GetSectionNames()
    {
        for (int maxsize = 500; true; maxsize *= 2)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[maxsize];
            int size = GetPrivateProfileString(0, "", "", bytes, maxsize, path);

            if (size < maxsize - 2)
            {
                string Selected = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0,
                               size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
                return Selected.Split(new char[] { '\0' });
            }
        }
    }

    public string[] GetEntryKeyNames(string section)
    {
        for (int maxsize = 500; true; maxsize *= 2)
        {
            byte[]  bytes   = new byte[maxsize];
            int     size        = GetPrivateProfileString(section, 0, "", bytes, maxsize, path);

            if (size < maxsize - 2)
            {
                string entries = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0,
                              size - (size > 0 ? 1 : 0));
                return entries.Split(new char[] { '\0' });
            }
        }
    }

    public object GetEntryKeyValue(string section, string entry)
    {
        for (int maxsize = 250; true; maxsize *= 2)
        {
            StringBuilder   result  = new StringBuilder(maxsize);
            int         size        = GetPrivateProfileString(section, entry, "",
                               result, maxsize, path);
            if (size < maxsize - 1)
            {
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my code in use:

```
List<string> PlacesList= new List<string>();
    List<string> PositionsList= new List<string>();

    private void btnReadini_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IniFile INI = new IniFile(@"C:\Races.ini");
        try
        {
            string[] SectionHeader = INI.GetSectionNames();
            if (SectionHeader != null)
            {
                foreach (string SecHead in SectionHeader)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("");
                    listBox1.Items.Add("[" +SecHead+"]");

                    string[] Entry = INI.GetEntryKeyNames(SecHead);
                    if (Entry != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string EntName in Entry)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add( EntName +"=" +
                                      INI.GetEntryKeyValue(SecHead, EntName));  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Error:  " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is an example ini file

```
[Places]
IOM=Isle of man
UK=United Kingdom
IRE=Ireland
[Races]
IOM=7
UK=6
[Positions]
WN=Win
2nd=Second
3rd=Third
4th=Fourth
```

I can currently read the ini file and display it in my listBox, what I wish to do now is save the name and value of section [Places] to a list called PlacesList and save the name and value of Positions to a list called PositionsList. With the current class I can read all sections, keys and values but how do i get only the data I want into the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with the code above, but rather than looping through all the sections you can just request the ones you need (the same could be applied to the entries if required).

```
List<string> PlacesList= new List<string>();
List<string> PositionsList= new List<string>();

public void btnReadini_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlacesList = ListEntries("Places");
    PositionsList = ListEntries("Positions");
}

public List<string> ListEntries(string sectionName)
{
    IniFile INI = new IniFile(@"C:\Races.ini");
    List<string> entries = null;

    string[] Entry = INI.GetEntryKeyNames(sectionName);
    if (Entry != null)
    {
        entries = new List<string>();

        foreach (string EntName in Entry)
        {
            entries.Add(EntName + "=" + INI.GetEntryKeyValue(sectionName, EntName));
        }
    }

    return entries;
}
```

However, rather than storing the data in a List you should look at using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110)), then you can use the key to lookup the value.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ListEntries(string sectionName)
{
    IniFile INI = new IniFile(@"C:\Races.ini");

    string[] Entry = INI.GetEntryKeyNames(sectionName);
    var entries = Entry .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                        .ToDictionary( m => m,
                                       m => INI.GetEntryKeyValue(sectionName, m) );

    return entries;
}
```

Comment: Great! Please can you mark this as the answer so others can find it easily in future...

Comment: Sorry Jon Clarke, I thought I had. It's marked now. Thanks